# Almost disjoint families on uncountable sets

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory, cardinals

Suppose that $\Gamma$ is an infinite set. Let us say that a family $\mathscr A$ of subsets of $\Gamma$ is almost disjoint, whenever for any two distinct sets $A_1, A_2\in \mathscr{A}$ the intersection $A_1\cap A_2$ has cardinality strictly less than $|\Gamma|$ and for any $A\in \mathscr{A}$ we have $|A|=|\Gamma|$.

> Does there always exist an almost disjoint family of cardinality $2^{|\Gamma|}$, or at least bigger than $|\Gamma|$?

When $\Gamma$ is countable, then of course this is the case, but I have a feeling this should fail for singular cardinals.

Comment: If $\kappa$ is regular then mad families have size $\geq\kappa^+$, I'm not sure what happens for singular $\kappa$

Comment: [Possibly related](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2004-132-11/S0002-9939-04-07580-X/S0002-9939-04-07580-X.pdf).

Comment: If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal then every maximal family of almost disjoint functions $f:\kappa\to\kappa$ (viewed as subsets of $\kappa\times\kappa$) has cardinality greater than $\kappa$.

Comment: @bof Is it true for singular $\kappa$?

Comment: I am absolutely sure I've seen this asked before. Here or on MathOverflow? I'm not sure.

Comment: In any case, it is an easy argument in the case of a regular $\kappa$ to show that given any $\{A_\alpha\mid\alpha<\kappa\}$ which is almost disjoint, then it is not maximal: the same diagonalisation as in the case of $\omega$, so at the very least MAD families are at least $\kappa^+$ in size. I suppose that this can be easily extended to singular cardinals (as in the screenshot from the paper) with the notice that the size of the family is now $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ instead.

Comment: @HanulJeon It doesn't matter if $\kappa$ is regular or singular. Suppose $F$ is a family of functions $f:\kappa\to\kappa$. If $|F|\le\kappa$ then we can write $F=\{f_\xi:\xi\lt\kappa\}$. Then we can define another function $g:\kappa\to\kappa$ so that $g(\alpha)\notin\{f_\xi(\alpha):\xi\le\alpha\}$, and we will have $|g\cap f|\lt\kappa$ for each $f\in F$, since $|g\cap f_\xi|\le|\xi|\lt\kappa$.

Comment: @bof How can we ensure that $\{f_\xi(\alpha):\xi\le\alpha\}$ is not $\kappa$? I asked it because your claim is seemingly contradicted with the linked paper (it claims that it is consistent that a mad family over $\aleph_\omega$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$ exists.)

Comment: @HanulJeon $|\{f_\xi(\alpha):\xi\le\alpha\}|\le|\alpha|+1\lt\kappa$.

Comment: @HanulJeon I'm talking about $\kappa$-sized subsets of $\kappa\times\kappa$ **of a special form**,  namely, functions $\kappa\to\kappa$. There may be (infinite) MAD families of subsets of $\kappa\times\kappa$ of cardinality less than $\kappa^+$, but they are not of this special form. All my argument (not original of course) was supposed to prove is that for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$ there **exists** an almost disjoint family on $\kappa$ of cardinality greater than $\kappa$.

Comment: @bof Aha, I get it, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:

> B. Balcar, P. Simon, [On collections of almost disjoint families](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/106679/CommentatMathUnivCarol_029-1988-4_2.pdf), *Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae*, **29** (1988), issue 4, 631-646.

[image]